# change icon when i drag my feature and i touch other feature openLayers

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers, drag, geojson

I need your help please I'm looking for trick which allows me to change the icon of feature when i touch other feature.
    What i need exactly when i drag my feature geojson_etat3 and i put in on mh_layer i want the icon of geojson_etat3 became ./images/Etat3.png

========================================================================

```
var geojson_etat3 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("etat3", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                        externalGraphic: './images/Etat3.png', 
                        graphicWidth: 21, 
                        graphicHeight: 25,
                        graphicYOffset: -24,
                        label : "${name}"
                        } ),

                        }),

                     // renderers: renderer,
                                          //'draggable': true,
            projection: epsg4326,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "data/data_etat3.json",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
                })

            });
```

this is my second feature which will be touched by geojson_etat3:

```
      var mh_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Equipe", {
                        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                            pointRadius: 5,
                            fillColor: "red",
                            strokeColor: "#0d4cd6",
                            strokeWidth: 1,
                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                            label:  "\n${name}"
                        } ),

                    }),

                         //renderers: renderer,
                        // 'draggable': true,
                        projection: epsg4326,
                        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                            url: "data/data_ot.json",
                            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                                extractAttributes: true
                            })
                        })

                    });
```

i did that but in vain :

```
controls = { 
   drag3 : new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(geojson_etat3,{ autoActivate: true, 
   overFeature: function(feature){ styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 
    "default":   new OpenLayers.Style({ externalGraphic: './images/Etat4.png' } ) }) } 

//onComplete: function() {alert('Are you sure this is the right postion?')} })
};

        for(var key in controls) {
                                map.addControl(controls[key]);
        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28330/openlayers-change-marker-icon-size-and-offset-after-drawn? That explains how to update an icon. Or do you need help with the intersection test between the two icons?